# Scientific data science conferences and journals

Tags: journals, conference, data-science

I would like to know which data *science* conference and journals exist out there. I do not mean business conferences that discuss data analytics (despite calling it data "science"), but actually scientific conferences / journals. You could say, I am talking about the "science of data science". Also I do not mean machine learning conferences / journals, but for data science.

Comment: This is probably off-topic, as a "shopping question". One lead you could try is the conferences by [ACM SIGKDD](https://www.kdd.org/about). Their [KDD](https://www.kdd.org/kdd2020) conference is considered top-tier, but I am not sure if it exactly fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such thing: the term "[data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science)" refers to a wide range of domains and applications which only have in common the fact that some form of knowledge/insight is extracted from raw data.

There are specific scientific fields (conferences, journals) for the techniques used in data science (essentially statistics and Machine Learning) as well as the applications of data science (a few examples among many: image processing, natural language processing, biomedical applications,...). There is no general scientific field of data science because it is simply too vast and diverse.

Comment: What I mean is methodologies regarding data science. The reason I am asking is, because I am developing a theory on what data science - from a theoretical, scientific perspective and not something that you would find on towardsdatascience. In my academic career I am a foundational researcher for machine learning, but conferences I publish (e.g. SIAM SDM, ECML-PKDD) are not about data science methodologies.

Comment: @Make42 I suspect that from an [epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) perspective data science is more an application than a pure science, in the sense that it's entirely based on other sciences (maths, statistics, ...) and its methodology follows general scientific principles. From this philosophical perspective it would be similar to medicine, which can be seen as an application using the principles of biology, chemistry, etc. Concretely I can't think of anything in data science methodology which is not inherited from other scientific fields, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You are a bit along the lines of my development (I dabble in philosophy as a "serious hobby"). Without going into detail regarding my methodology/definition, the result of my definition of data science is that you could say it is "mathematical epistemology" - not the actual appliance, but the methodology. Data analytics would then be appliance of the data science principles (your "medicine"). You could say that data science is to data analytics, as physic is to mechanical engineering. With that, a company would hire a data scientist / physicist to work on an an *engineering* project.

Comment: Ok I see. It looks like your work is at the intersection of various fields, it can be tricky to find the right venue to publish it in such cases. Maybe you could try to find where other people have published similar "high level" scientific work? I'm thinking maybe some general AI journals/conferences would be an option, because there is also an overlap there between ML, philosophical concepts, societal implications, ethics... I'm not really sure, it's just an idea.